# <h:outputscript> tag not working?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

i am not able to  invoke a function in my  javascript.  i used   to invoke the function inthe script.can u suggest me the way to accomplish my task?
my code as below

## Thank You For  Registering

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="panel1">
<h:outputText value="user name" ></h:outputText>   
<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{login1.userName}"  required="true">
</h:inputText>

<h:outputText value="password"></h:outputText>
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login1.passWord}">
</h:inputSecret>

<h:outputText value="confirmPassword"></h:outputText>
<h:inputSecret value="#{login1.passWord}">
</h:inputSecret>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="panel2">
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="submit" 
action="#{login1.insertNewUser}"     onclick="test()" ></h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid >
<h:outputLabel >do u want to check once?</h:outputLabel>
<h:commandLink id="link" action="login" disabled="true">Login</h:commandLink>
<h:outputScript name="UI/script.js" ></h:outputScript>
</h:panelGrid>



</h:form>
```

my javascript:script.js

```
function test(){
var link=document.getElementById("myform:link").getAttribute("disabled");
alert(link);
alert("hi");
}
```

nothing  showing with this . i am using jsf2.o. i am thankful to you for any response in advance

Comment: just call `var link=document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("disabled"); alert(link)`

Comment: even it dint work out

Comment: Do you have *script.js* stored in the *<WEBAPP-ROOT>/resources* directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script.js must be inside /webapp/resources/UI/ or /war/resources/UI/ or whatever.
And use as `<h:outputScript library="UI" name="script.js" />`